# Emulator won't reload code

Tags: android-intent

1. This is my code

   ```
   public class MainActivity extends Activity {
   Button btn;

   public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
       super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
       setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
       btn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
       btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
           @Override
           public void onClick(View v) {
               Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this,
                       socialnetworking.class);
               startActivity(intent);    
           }
       });    
   }
   ```

   }
2. But I'm getting this message from my console:

   ```
       [2013-05-17 17:57:44 - NXTRemoteControl] ------------------------------
       [2013-05-17 17:57:44 - NXTRemoteControl] Android Launch!
       [2013-05-17 17:57:44 - NXTRemoteControl] adb is running normally.
       [2013-05-17 17:57:44 - NXTRemoteControl] Performing com.example.nxtremotecontrol.MainActivity activity launch
       [2013-05-17 17:57:44 - NXTRemoteControl] Automatic Target Mode: using existing emulator 'emulator-5554' running compatible AVD 'GalaxyNexus'
       [2013-05-17 17:57:46 - NXTRemoteControl] Application already deployed. No need to reinstall.
       [2013-05-17 17:57:46 - NXTRemoteControl] Starting activity com.example.nxtremotecontrol.MainActivity on device emulator-5554
       [2013-05-17 17:57:47 - NXTRemoteControl] ActivityManager: Starting: Intent { act=android.intent.action.MAIN cat=[android.intent.category.LAUNCHER] cmp=com.example.nxtremotecontrol/.MainActivity }
       [2013-05-17 17:57:47 - NXTRemoteControl] ActivityManager: Warning: Activity not started, its current task has been brought to the front
   ```

   1. I'm a bit confused as to what it means by it has been brought to the front, and this whole thing as a whole

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The emulator is just telling you that

1. Your application already is on the "device"
2. It can't detect any apparent changes
3. It's already running, and therefore it just needs to be brought to the front

If you need to refresh it, you can either

- Uninstall it and start running it again
- Change it and start running it again
  or
- Clean your project and start running it again

Comment: You're welcome! If my answer solved your problem, choose the check-mark next to it.